# How to use C program for multiple files

Tags: c, bash

I have C program which take two argument, 1st is filename.txt and 2nd is some parameter. And, finally generate some score. Now, I have 10,000 of file in folder naming 1.txt .... 10,000.txt, and I want to calculate score of all the 10,000 file using that C program and want to put all the score in the file result.txt.

How can I automatize this thing.

Comment: please show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: I hope you have heard of loops?

Comment: Do you need the code for taking arguments for the C program, or some shell command to provide the list of files to your C program ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things

1. Write an external script that calls your program sequentially with all the files as arguments.
2. Alter your program so that it cycles over all the files. You can use sprintf to iterate over the filenames.

   ```
    char filename[50];
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; ++i) {
      sprintf(filename, "%d.txt", i);
      FILE* file = fopen(filename);
      // .. do stuff
      fclose(file);
    }
   ```

Comment: The first won't work, he wants to combine the data from all the files, not operate on them separately.

Comment: Depends on how would OP do it. I would make the script aggregate the data but that depends on the requirements. It may be the case that original program can not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Tree ways.

The first one is by giving in argument all of you files :

./myProgram 1.txt -args 2.txt -args ...

The second one is by giving all you files names, then you arguments
./myProgram *.txt -args

The third one is by writing a program using a loop in wich you look for all the files

Answer (score 0):

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* open file argv[1] with options in argv[2] */
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

Run it with

```
./program directory/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

1. As an argument pass directory name where files are stored. Giving
   all file names as arguments is impossible when you have so much of
   those. I am not sure what current version of C standard says but
   ANSI C at least was mentioning that compiler should be able to take
   care of at minimum 31 arguments of function so having 10,000 is quite
   big amount.
2. Then use e.g. `readdir()` function to iterate through all files in given directory and do job you need to perform.